# Given locally compact topology $(X,\tau)$, if $\tau\subset \tau '$ is $(X,\tau ')$ locally compact?

Tags: general-topology

I believe that this maybe true because $\tau=Power(X)$ is always locally compact. But I maybe wrong.

Edit: Wait wait. I see the trivial example now. But what if $\tau$ is infinite?(which is the idea I had in mind)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is obviously false. Let $(X,\tau')$ be any non-locally compact space and let $\tau$ be the trivial topology on $X$.

If you want a more concrete (and possibly useful) example: The Sorgenfrey line is not locally compact, but the real line is.

Comment: What if $\tau$ is infinite?